# How to code external images and icons in a Squarespace site?

Tags: html, image, icons, squarespace

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nA2Z.png)My icons and images that I coded through HTML on squarespace is not showing. The only thing that I can see is a thumbnail icon but no image. Also, the same goes for my icons which are in .svg form.

```
<section id="collaborate-services-2">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="services">
                    <div>
                      <img class=”img-consulting” src=”” />
                        <div class="services-1"></div>
                            <div class="clr"></div>
                            <h3>Consulting</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img class=”img-training” src=”” />
                            <div class="services-2"></div>
                        <div class="clr"></div>
                        <h3>Training</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img class=”img-speaking” src=”” />
                            <div class="services-3"></div>
                        <div class="clr"></div>
                        <h3>Public Speaking</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
              <btn>Ask Me</btn>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer and add the code as you have added it in Squarespace? Could you also add a screenshot of what you're seeing or a link to the page in question? Finally, are you adding it via a code block?

Comment: I've added the code and yes I am using a code block.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to add external images on Squarespace code block:

1. The image/ icon has to be hosted on another site and you put the link on Squarespace in a code block,
2. You upload your images in the gallery section or in an unlinked page. After upload you will get a squarespace link generated for the image. Copy it's image address using browser options and use it in a code block.

Note: if you delete the image, the link will also be removed. The link won't get deleted on the same day. For Squarespace will keep the image cached for a few more days.

Comment: Thank you. I've attempted the section option but images aren't showing yet. I'm assuming because I'm in preview mode.

Comment: I have live websites with images added like this. May be you should check the image link on to a new browser tab and see if the image can be seen. And if you can't see the image it means you did not copy the image link properly.